# str_replace string in array number auto increasing

Tags: php, string, arrays, str-replace

what we can do to remove **page=2&**
From:

```
"page=2&param1=value1&param2=value2" or
"param1=value1&page=2&param2=value2".
```

become:

```
"param1=value1&param2=value2" or
"param1=value1&param2=value2".
```

in case of page=2, 2 is any natural no. i.e. (0 to 32000).

Regards,

Comment: Could `page=2` also be at the end of the string, i.e. not followed by an `&`?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the string to an array, unset page from the array, and then use [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to reconstruct the result.

Code example:

```
$str = 'page=2&param1=value1&param2=value2';
$arr = array();
parse_str($str, $arr);
unset($arr['page']);
echo http_build_query($arr);
```

Comment: Creating, unsetting, and imploding seems like a bit of overkill to me but it would look a hell of a lot cleaner than regex.

Comment: Thank You Mark for you input so far, but how to use http_build_query related to my question, and used for pafination?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $str = trim(preg_replace("/\bpage=\d+&?/", "", $str), "$");
```

The regexp:

```
\b        # Match a "boundary" point (start of new word)
page=     # Match 'page='
\d+       # Match 1 or more digits
&?        # Match a '&' if it exists
```

The trim around the outside will remove any trailing `&` that might be leftover.

If you want to trim anything you can replace the `\d+` with `[^&]+` to match any characters other than `&`.

```
 $str = trim(preg_replace("/\bpage=[^&]+&?/", "", $str), "$");
```

Comment: this will leave `&` at the end of `"param1=value1&param2=value2&page=2"`

Comment: @vava - added a trim to take care of that case

Comment: What if the visitor has manually typed in a page that is not a number? how if to parse the query string, explicitly remove the key in question, and rebuild it, but thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this will let you remove an arbitrary page (as long as you know the number):

```
function replacePage($querystring, $page = 1) {
    return str_replace('page='.$page.'&', '', $querystring);
}
```

As a side note, using regular expressions is not the optimum way to code if they can be avoided.  They are slow and should be replaced with other methods such as `str_replace` or tokenizing where possible.  Personally I'd use my method If I knew what page I had to remove from the query string as it will run much faster than a preg_replace.

Comment: did you echo the data? i.e. `echo replacePage($myQueryString, 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

using explode ?

```
$urlString = "page=2&param1=value1&param2=value2";
$arr = explode('&',$urlString);
print_r( $arr );
foreach( $arr as $var => $val ) {
    if( substr( $val, 0, 6 ) == 'param2' ) {
        unset( $arr[ $var ] );
    }
}
$urlString = implode('&',$arr);
```

Comment: output of your code: Array ( [0] => page=2 [1] => param1=value1 [2] => param2=value2 )  it's look not seem like my first posting, but thank for your input